# concatenate two columns values pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe data :

```
Cluster OsId    BrowserId   PageId  VolumePred  ConversionPred  
255      7         11          17   1149582        4.0  
607     18         99          16   917224         8.0  
22       0         12          14   1073848        4.0
```

I would like to add new column "OSBROWSER" which is the concatenation of two columns : OsId and BrowserId.

The result should be like this :

```
Cluster OsId    BrowserId   PageId  VolumePred  ConversionPred  OSBROWSER
255      7         11          17   1149582        4.0           (7, 11)
607     18         99          16   917224         8.0           (18, 99)
22       0         12          14   1073848        4.0           (0, 12)
```

I try like this :

```
data['OSBrowser'] =  data["OsId"] + data["BrowserId"]
```

But it gave me the sum of the two clumns values

Any idea please? thanks you

SOLUTION :

```
data['OSBrowser']  = list(zip(data.OsId, data.BrowserId))
```

Comment: Thanks, yours was the solution that I required with a minor changing. I used my_dataframe['my_colnames'] inside zip( ) method. Best solution found after working for days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would convert the columns to string, I think that's what you're looking to do.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(((123, 456, 789), (98, 765, 432)), columns=('a', 'b', 'c'))

df['a_str'] = df['a'].astype(str)
df['b_str'] = df['b'].astype(str)

df['ab'] = df['a_str'] + df['b_str']
```

df then looks like this

```
     a    b    c a_str b_str      ab
0  123  456  789   123   456  123456
1   98  765  432    98   765   98765
```

Then you can just drop a_str and b_str

```py
df = df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab']]
```

Comment: Thank you  guys for your responses! kind regards

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution:

```
data['OSBrowser'] = data[["OsId", "BrowserId"]].apply(tuple, axis=1)
```